# Recommend a fast sorting algorithm for local order among the segment in the array

Tags: arrays, sorting, cuda, parallel-processing

Sorting data in each segment in an array on GPU, the size of segment is 32, and there are no sorting or merging further for different segments. So I load the data of the each segment into the shared memory from global memory, and store the data into the global memory after I finished sorting of each segment. What's the parallel algorithm is prefer for higher throughput?

Comment: Usually this kind of question is deprecated on StackOverflow because they tend to attrack opinionated answers. If I correctly understand, you have to order not a whole array, but only `32` element segments. In this case, have you considered using warp shuffle operations if you have a card with compute capability at least `3.x`? Shuffle operations offer performance advantage against shared memory. Take a look at the Tuning CUDA Applications for Kepler Application Note.

Comment: You might also look at [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/), but I agree with @JackOLantern in the comment above.  32 elements is small enough that you may find best performance by creating your own sort routine, rather than using a canned routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since segment sizes are all 32, I personally suggest [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). There's also [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6339592) paper you can refer to.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use the in-warp [bitonic sort](http://www.tools-of-computing.com/tc/CS/Sorts/bitonic_sort.htm), which is implemented very efficiently using the SHFL instruction of the Kepler architecture. See code in this GTC 2013 presentation:

[Kepler's SHUFFLE(SHFL) Instruction: Tips and Tricks](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3174-Kepler-Shuffle-Tips-Tricks.pdf)

Using it will also mean you won't need to bother with shared memory, just load one value by each thread into a register.